# Calculated SUMPRODUCT as formula for Excel Data validation

Tags: excel, validation

Is it possible somehow to use SUMPRODUCT as a custom formula for Data validation function?
if I put smth like:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(J!$B$21)=DAY(TS!$A$5:$A$369)); --(MONTH(J!$B$21)=MONTH(TS!$A$5:$A$369)); --(YEAR(J!$B$21)=YEAR(TS!$A$5:$A$369));TS!$C$5:$C$369)>=0

I get a warning about inconsistent formula.
On its own formula works well.

Comment: You need to replace all ; (semicolon) with , (comma).

Comment: This formula will return True or False, which is a single value. What are you trying to limit the values to through data validation? This validation is for which cell?

Comment: No, on my system the separator is ";", not ",".<br> Formula does not return true or false, it returns value in one of the cells TS!$C$5:$C$369, for which all three criteria evaluate to 1 (the effect of --). Formula on itself works great if employed in standard way, but I can not use it as a criteria for Data validation.

Comment: ups... the comment was about ">=0" part - I'd like to limit input in the specific cell (via Data validation) to be less or equal to the looked-up value in the specific cell in the TS sheet (entered value will be afterwards subtracted from the specific cell in TS). The structures of both sheets differ - while the structure of TS is static with changing values, the other is just a collection of un-sortet dates with user-entered values.I try to avoid macros as much as possible.